# Can anyone help to identify the uniforms in this photograph?

Tags: identification, uniform

[image]Can anyone help to identify the uniforms in this photograph?

All I know is that Kroonstad was then part of the Orange River Colony - formed around 1900

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome.  A higher resolution photo would be a big help.  There is often good detail in small old photos if you take a sharp enough picture.  What do you know about the history of the photo and the people pictured.  Is there anything on the back?  Please add these facts to your question.

Comment: They look similar to Orange River Colony uniforms, but the hats threw me off.

Comment: The caps look vaguely like Glengarry caps to me, which seem typically to have long dangling tassels, visible on the gent on (our) right, facing us frontally, with tassel over his left shoulder.  The other gent seems to have his tassel begin behind the nape of his neck. His left cuff seems to show some badge or lace decoration.